# como faço pra salvar um vetor alocado dinamicamente e retornar como um ponteiro na funçao?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void soma(float *vimp,float *vr ,int qnt, float *med, int a);
void maiorvalor(float *vimp, float mval, int qnt );

main(){
     float med, vimp, mval,vr;
     int qnt,i,a;

    printf("informe a quantidade de pessoas a serem fiscalizadas: \n");
    scanf("%d",&qnt);

    soma(&vimp,&vr, qnt, &med, a);
    maiorvalor(&vimp,mval,qnt);

    printf("a soma de todos os valores: %f\n", vr);
    printf("a media dos valores: %f\n", med);
    printf("o maior valor foi: %f\n",mval);
    printf("a quantidade de pessoas acima da media foi: %d\n",a);

    for(i=0;i<qnt;i++){
        printf(" %d valor : %f\n", i+1,vimp);
    }   
  system("pause");  
}
void soma(float *vimp, float *vr,int qnt, float *med, int a){
    int i;  
    vimp = (float*) malloc (qnt*sizeof(float));
    for(i=0;i<qnt;i++){
        printf("informe o valor em debito da %d%c pessoa\n",i+1,167);
        scanf("%f",vimp);

        *vr= *vimp+*vr;
        *med=*vr/qnt;
    }   

    for(i=0; i<qnt;i++){
        if(vimp>med){
            a++;
        }
    }  
}
void maiorvalor(float *vimp, float mval, int qnt){

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<qnt;i++){
        if(*vimp>mval){
            mval=*vimp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem bastantes erros no programa, mas começo por responder diretamente à questão.

### Retorno do vetor

Para retornar um vetor alocado dinamicamente basta alterar o respetivo tipo de retorno e utilizar a *keyword* return. Na sua função `soma`:

```
void soma( ...
```

Altera para:

```
float* soma(...
```

Para jogar com o tipo do vetor. E agora no final dessa função retorna o vetor alocado:

```
float* soma(...) {
    ...
    float *vimp = (float*) malloc (qnt*sizeof(float)); //alocação
    ...
    return vimp; //retorno
}
```

No `main` tem de capturar apropriadamente:

```
int main(){
    ...
    float* vetor_capturado = soma(...);
```

### Correção

Comecemos por corrigir o programa utilizando já o retorno do vetor. Em vários sítios está a utilizar `*vimp` diretamente sendo esse o ponteiro aponta para o vetor:

```
*vr= *vimp+*vr;
```

Dessa forma não irá conseguir aceder a todos os elementos e apenas o primeiro. Corrija e simplifique, alterando para:

```
*vr += vimp[i];
```

Tentando alterar o mínimo possível da sua lógica de forma a que o programa funcione:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Retorna agora um vetor de floats e não recebe vimp.
//O parametro a é agora também passado como ponteiro
float* soma(float *vr ,int qnt, float *med, int *a);

//mval precisa de ser passado como ponteiro para ser alteravel
void maiorvalor(float *vimp, float *mval, int qnt );

int main(){
    float med, mval,vr;
    int qnt,i,a = 0; //faltava a=0

    printf("informe a quantidade de pessoas a serem fiscalizadas: \n");
    scanf("%d",&qnt);

    float* vimp = soma(&vr, qnt, &med, &a); //nova captura do vetor
    maiorvalor(vimp,&mval,qnt);

    printf("a soma de todos os valores: %f\n", vr);
    printf("a media dos valores: %f\n", med);
    printf("o maior valor foi: %f\n",mval);
    printf("a quantidade de pessoas acima da media foi: %d\n",a);

    for(i=0;i<qnt;i++){
        printf(" %d valor : %f\n", i+1,vimp[i]); //vimp[i] que faltava
    }

    free(vimp); //liberar a memoria alocada na função
    return 0;
}

float* soma(float *vr,int qnt, float *med, int *a){
    int i;
    float *vimp = (float*) malloc (qnt*sizeof(float));
    for(i=0;i<qnt;i++){
        printf("informe o valor em debito da %d%c pessoa\n",i+1,167);
        scanf("%f",&vimp[i]);
        *vr += vimp[i]; //simplificado
    }

    *med=*vr/qnt; //media so calculada no fim

    for(i=0; i<qnt;i++){
        if(vimp[i]>*med){ //faltava vimp[i] e *med
            (*a)++; //faltava *a
        }
    }

    return vimp; //novo retorno
}

void maiorvalor(float *vimp, float *mval, int qnt){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<qnt;i++){
        if(vimp[i]>*mval){
            *mval=vimp[i];
        }
    }
}
```

[Veja o resultado desta versão no Ideone](https://ideone.com/8bUV9S)

É importante salientar que o vetor que estava a alocar na função `soma` iria gerar uma fuga de memória a menos que fosse destruído em algum lado por si, e por esse motivo adicionei também o `free` a fim de tornar evidente a sua necessidade.

### Melhorias

Apesar de já funcionar pode melhorar em alguns aspetos:

- Nomes das variáveis e funções devem ser o mais evidentes possíveis, e por isso um nome como `a` não é de todo bom.
- Neste caso em particular do seu programa que é simples, torna-se mais facil não ter a declaração à priori das funções fazendo com que cada alteração necessite de ser feita apenas num local.
- Devolver o maior valor do vetor como retorno da função `maiorvalor`.

Aplicando essas melhorias:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float* somar(float *soma,int qnt, float *media, int *acima_media){
    int i;
    float *debitos = malloc (qnt*sizeof(float));
    for(i = 0;i < qnt;i++){
        printf("informe o valor em debito da %d%c pessoa\n", i+1, 167);
        scanf("%f", &debitos[i]);
        *soma += debitos[i];
    }

    *media=*soma / qnt;

    for(i=0; i<qnt;i++){
        if(debitos[i]>*media){
            (*acima_media)++;
        }
    }
    return debitos;
}

float calcular_maior(float *debitos, int qnt){
    int i;
    float maior = debitos[0];
    for(i = 1;i < qnt;i++){
        if(debitos[i] > maior)
            maior = debitos[i];
    }
    return maior;
}

int main(){
    float media, soma;
    int qnt, acima_media = 0;

    printf("informe a quantidade de pessoas a serem fiscalizadas: \n");
    scanf("%d",&qnt);

    float* debitos = somar(&soma, qnt, &media, &acima_media);
    float maior = calcular_maior(debitos, qnt);

    printf("a soma de todos os valores: %f\n", soma);
    printf("a media dos valores: %f\n", media);
    printf("o maior valor foi: %f\n", maior);
    printf("a quantidade de pessoas acima da media foi: %d\n", acima_media);

    int i;
    for(i = 0;i<qnt;i++){
        printf(" %d valor : %f\n", i+1,debitos[i]);
    }

    free(debitos);
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja também esta segunda versão no Ideone](https://ideone.com/QAeBU9)

Note que não fiz alguns testes de sanidade, como por exemplo garantir que não chama a função `calcular_maior` com tamanho `0` que irá gerar um acesso invalido na memoria.

### Organizando com estruturas

Utilizando estruturas consegue ainda organizar mais o seu código se separar cada parte da lógica no local correto.  Dessa forma pode ter uma função apenas para fazer a leitura dos valores, e outra apenas para totalizar, sendo que esta ultima devolveria os resultados todos numa estrutura.

Com isto consegue:

- Não ter que passar ponteiros a alterar o que complicam a lógica
- Separar a leitura de processamento

Resultado final:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Estatisticas {
    float soma;
    float media;
    float maior;
    int acima_media;
} Estatisticas;

float* ler_debitos(int qnt){
    int i;
    float *debitos = malloc (qnt * sizeof(float));
    for(i = 0;i < qnt;i++){
        printf("informe o valor em debito da %d%c pessoa\n", i+1, 167);
        scanf("%f", &debitos[i]);
    }

    return debitos;
}

Estatisticas totalizar(float* debitos, int qnt){
    Estatisticas totais = {0};    
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < qnt;i++){
        totais.soma += debitos[i];
        if (debitos[i] > totais.maior){
            totais.maior = debitos[i];
        }
    }

    totais.media = totais.soma / qnt;

    for (i = 0; i < qnt;i++){
        if (debitos[i] > totais.media){
            totais.acima_media++;
        }
    }
    return totais;
}

int main(){
    int qnt;
    printf("informe a quantidade de pessoas a serem fiscalizadas: \n");
    scanf("%d",&qnt);

    float* debitos = ler_debitos(qnt);
    Estatisticas totais = totalizar(debitos, qnt);

    printf("a soma de todos os valores: %f\n", totais.soma);
    printf("a media dos valores: %f\n", totais.media);
    printf("o maior valor foi: %f\n", totais.maior);
    printf("a quantidade de pessoas acima da media foi: %d\n", totais.acima_media);

    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < qnt;i++){
        printf(" %d valor : %f\n", i+1, debitos[i]);
    }

    free(debitos);
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja esta ultima versão também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/qcrIUi)